# Realm v10 database in Xamarin iOS project won't build - "No matching framework found inside...realm-wrappers.xcframework"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm, visual-studio-2022, xcframework

I'm attempting to upgrade the Realm database version I'm using in my Xamarin Forms project, from v5 up to the latest v10.

The original Realm database has been working fine for years, however when I try to use Realm v10 I can build the Android project successfully, but when I attempt to build the iOS project I get the error:

"No matching framework found inside 'C:\Users\MyName.nuget\packages\realm\10.11.1\build..\native\ios\universal\realm-wrappers.xcframework'"

...and I'm at a loss. A Google search is very scant on the subject, so I don't have any direction to get this build working.

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2022, linked to a macOS Monterey build server with Xcode 13.3.1

EDIT: As advised, I have opened an issue on GitHub for this:
https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/2914

Comment: Realm engineer here - does the issue still occur if you build a brand new project with the v10 NuGet, or if you try to build the same project directly on the build server with Visual Studio for Mac? I've seen similar issues before in other v10 upgrades and most of the time making sure to clear build caches (all `bin` and `obj` folders in your solution, and relevant caches on the builder server) after the upgrade solves them. If that doesn't help, please open an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues.

Comment: @Tayschrenn It's a Realm upgrade in an existing app, so I've not tried a fresh project. The build server was brand new for this build, so there's no cruft on that to clear out, but I will try the simple bin/obj folder purge and see if that helps.

Comment: @Tayschrenn No luck I'm afraid: I've deleted all obj/bin folders, plus all build server caches, and even a new project on a fresh build server, but still no joy. I'll open an issue on Github.

Comment: For posterity's sake, according to the findings in https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/2914 the problem was that the project targets the ARMv7s architecture, which Realm doesn't support. Removing the extra architecture fixed the build.

Comment: @Tayschrenn Do you want to post this as an answer and I'll accept it?